# How do I activate this platform?

Tags: sideway

So I've been playing the Sideway demo and I got 4 out of the 5 secrets. There's a certain platform I can't reach, and nearby there's a special platform which I can't stand on, but glows when I jump over it. Here's a screenshot in which I added an arrow indicating the unreachable platform and a circle around the glowing platform (since Nox is currently "over" it, you can see a faint purple glow there, otherwise it doesn't appear):

[image: vandalized screenshot]

(I've also added a "graffiti" tag of my own, just to stay loyal to the overall feel of the game)

What is the meaning of this glow? Is there any way in which I can activate this platform? Alternatively, is there any other way to reach that unreachable platform on the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a "paintable" platform. The ability to paint a platform is obtained in level 2, and is triggered by hitting the "use" key when the platform is flowing. In this specific level, using that platform is the only way to get 100% tags and 5/5 secrets.

Since this platform is at level 1 and the ability to paint it is only obtained at level 2, it means that:

1. If you want 100% completion, you have to play the level again later.
2. This cannot be accessed in the demo, which only includes level 1.